# How to change <td> header dynamically?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, jsp-tags

Here when i select lose from drop down then I want to change label from win to lose, is it possible to change label (header).

```
<td>
    <select name="action" id="action" class="mondatory" onchange="getAlert()">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="win">win</option>
        <option value="los">lose</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>win</td>
<td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="win"   id="win" size="10" class="mondatory">
</td>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Start by creating `getAlert` function and ask here if your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Are you asking about just changing it within the browser, which would be done with JavaScript? If so, why the Java, JSP, and jsp-tags tags on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set onChange event listener on the select with vanilla javascript, for example:

```
//html
<select id='mySelect' onchange='mySelectOnChange()'>
    <option value='win'>win</option>
    <option value='lose'>lose</option>
</select>
<span id='result'></span>
//js
function mySelectOnChange() {
    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#mySelect').value
}
```

You can do it much more simpler if you use any framework/library supporting two-way data binding. e.g. [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) / [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)

Comment: Awesome , Thank You Very much for fast reply bro

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
<td>
<select name="action" id="action" class="mondatory" onchange="getAlert()">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="win">win</option>
    <option value="lose">lose</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><span id="header_td"></span></td>
<td align="left">
     <input type="text" name="win" id="win" size="10" class="mondatory">
</td>
```

In your script

```
<script>

function getAlert() {
    var selected_value = document.getElementById('action').value;
    $("#header_td").text(selected_value);
}

</script>
```